# Adfs Saml request fails via Passport-saml

Tags: saml, passport.js, adfs, adfs2.0

As am requesting for token from ADFS2.0 server, for that i have used passport-saml for my nodejs app. I can able to login with my valid username and password into the server, after login am getting error page

```
 There was a problem accessing the site. Try to browse to the site again.
 If the problem persists, contact the administrator of this site and provide the reference                     
 number to identify the problem.
 Reference number: 321b1aac-fea7-4ae4-8e07-665c343903fa
```

error showed on **Adfs Event Viewer** is

```
 The request specified an assertion consumer service  that is not  configured or not   
 supported on the relying party 'https://sample.company.com'. 
 Request parameters: '', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST','https://sample.company.com' 
 Relying party: https://sample.company.com 

 This request failed.
```

Am searching in net but yet to find exact answer, i dont know how to configure relying party trust for endpoint tab on properties. what url i have to give, is there anything i have to do for SAML request and response from ADFS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you haven't configured the AssertionConsumerURL on ADFS Relying Party. This is on the ADFS -> Relying Party -> Endpoints.

You can also try this package

https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2